# find expressions with exec

Tags: bash, find

I had a bit of trouble with find. This didn't do what I expected:

```
find . -iname "*.hh" -or -iname "*.h" -exec grep -inH "IDENTIFIER" {} \;
```

I expected it to grep in both *.hh and *.h files but it only greps the result of -iname "*.h". I resorted to using xargs to solve it.

```
find . -iname "*.hh" -or -iname "*.h" | xargs grep -inH "IDENTIFIER"
```

But is there a way to use -exec without writing it twice like this:

```
find . -iname "*.hh" -exec grep -inH "IDENTIFIER" {} \; -or -iname "*.h" -exec grep -inH "IDENTIFIER" {} \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

```
find . \( -iname "*.hh" -o -iname "*.h" \) -exec ...
```

to find both *.hh and *.h files.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with the regex option to grep:

`find . -regex '.*\.hh?' -exec  grep -inH "IDENTIFIER" {} \;`